# How to check already a row exist in current month and year

Tags: php, mysql

I have a process table which contains company_id (varchar) and process_date (date). Program insert one row in the table at first execution (before inserting one row there are some processing and insert some data to another table). The program executing every week using a cron job. If there is one row existing in the process table in current month skip the further process. So how to check already a row exist in the process table in the current month and year.

Comment: Please show some code

Comment: Post your queries. Post your table structure. Show us what you've done.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a small table, the easiest thing to do is:

```
where year(process_date) = year(now()) and month(process_date) = month(now())
```

This `where` clause cannot take advantage of an index on `process_date`, but it should be fine for up to a few thousand rows.